# Inline code with and is not working but using the regular if works

Tags: javascript

I have the following code amd it gives me compilation error:

```
for(var i in test){
     (this.watcherFailureCount> 10) && break
}
```

However the following works:

```
if(this.watcherFailureCount> 10)
{ 
  break 
}
```

Am I missing anything here? why the first one is not working for me?

Comment: You should show more code (preferably the loop your if-statement is in). `break` is only valid within a loop, switch, or with labels. Your second code-block by itself is syntactically invalid. Either way, `break` is not an expression, so pairing it with `&&` won't work.

Comment: @chazsolo there is a loop I will update it. what do you mean by expression?

Comment: Because `break` is a command, not a value that can be used as part of a conditional test like in your first attempt. It works in your second because you are invoking the command and not trying to evaluate it as part of a condition.

Comment: @ScottMarcus makes more sense now

Comment: @chazsolo It's a little more involved than that. It's ok for part of an expression to not evaluate to anything. In that case, the expression returns `undefined`, but `break` is a reserved word representing a command in the language and its use here represents a syntax error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus fair point - learned something myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The && tries to evaluate your expression and cast its return value to boolean. The break you use is a keyword that controls the loop and should not be used in expressions.

Some languages allow that but it just seems that js doesn’t. And to be fair it is ok not to because is missleading. Imagine conditions like: a && b && break && c && d = a.

There is no real benefit in the first option unless you codegolf or something, and if you codegolf you chosed the wrong language :).

Answer (score 1):

Dont fully understand what youre trying to achieve here however impretty sure the first code snippet is incorrect syntax.
If you want that as an inline if statement try:

```
if(this.watcherFailureCount>10)break;
```

However ensure if you are using break that it is inside of some form of code loop like a while or a for loop. And using && with break is invalid as break cannot be a true or false statement so it cant be used like that.